# ion side menu blocks scrolling on ion-content

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

This is the side menu code

```
<ion-side-menu-content>

    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
        <ion-nav-back-button class="button-icon ion-ios7-arrow-left"></ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>

    <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" ng-click="toggleLeft()">
        </button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>

    <ion-nav-view name="mainContainer" animation="slide-left-right"></ion-nav-view>

</ion-side-menu-content>
```

the problem is that when side menu is open i can't scroll the content.

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/raeGpW)

Comment: Do you have a codepen to show the issue?

Comment: yes i have... see below code

Comment: It may be by design... (see their vanilla sidemenu sample: http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/tcIGK). Let me check with the Ionic guys and get back to you.

Comment: Yep. It's be design. see: https://twitter.com/andrewmcgivery/status/544287221785051136